# how to download pdf file in iOS?

Tags: swift

[image: example]

I am converting base64 to pdf file in local.

```
func saveBase64StringToPDF(_ base64String: String)
   {
    guard
        var documentsURL = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last,
        let convertedData = Data(base64Encoded: base64String)
        else {
            //handle error when getting documents URL
            return
    }

    documentsURL.appendPathComponent("yourFileName.pdf")

    do {
        try convertedData.write(to: documentsURL)
    } catch {
        //handle write error here
    }

    print(documentsURL)
}
```

From above method I am getting a path pdf file

> file:///Users/captivatesoft/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/63D1814B-1010-4694-883E-D2EE75C386DD/data/Containers/Data/Application/1F39B567-F470-4B7E-9A9C-4723ADFDC428/Documents/yourFileName.pdf

Is there any way to download this pdf file or to show pdf in safari?

Answer (score 1):

```
    var pdfURL = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in:                 .userDomainMask)).last! as URL
    pdfURL = pdfURL.appendingPathComponent( "example.pdf") as URL

    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: pdfURL)
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x:20,y:20,width:view.frame.size.width-40, height:view.frame.size.height-40))
    webView.load(data, mimeType: "application/pdf", characterEncodingName:"", baseURL: pdfURL.deletingLastPathComponent())
    view.addSubview(webView)
```

Comment: Get your file url from this code -   var pdfURL = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in:                 .userDomainMask)).last! as URL
    pdfURL = pdfURL.appendingPathComponent( "example.pdf") as URL

Answer (score 0):

To open the PDF in Safari you could just do

`UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: <the link for the PDF>))`

Now to download a PDF or anything from a URL, you could just do

`let pdfData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: <the link for the PDF>))`

NOTE: `try Data(contentsOf: url)` will block the thread, so you might want to do it on a different thread like this :

```
 DispatchQueue.global.async { [weak self] in
        if let pdfData = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
           // Now you can do anything with the data
        }
    }
```

Comment: Getting error...please check my image in above question

Comment: Yes because it seems that documentsURL is already a URL. You can do UIApplication.shared.openURL(documentsURL)

Comment: I am calling UIApplication.shared.openURL(documentsURL) in saveBase64StringToPDF method but it's not working

Comment: Does this work :  UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com") ?

Comment: UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "stackoverflow.com")  is not working

Comment: UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "stackoverflow.com"))

Comment: UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "stackoverflow.com")) this one is also not working

Answer (score 0):

First, you can not download pdf file in iOS, it means you cannot save pdf file in iBook or Album.

You can fetch pdf file data from file URL then you can do follows:

1. Open in Safari browser from the app.
2. You can show pdf file in WKWebView within the app.
3. You can use "QuickLook" framework to show the pdf file.

Using WebView:

```
if let url = URL(string:string) {
   webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
}
```

Comment: thank you..but this file file:///Users/captivatesoft/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/63D1814B-1010-4694-883E-D2EE75C386DD/data/Containers/Data/Application/1F39B567-F470-4B7E-9A9C-4723ADFDC428/Documents/yourFileName.pdf is not working in WKWebView

Comment: if let url = URL(string:"file:///Users/captivatesoft/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/63D1814B-1010-4694-883E-D2EE75C386DD/data/Containers/Data/Application/5C00DD35-CF90-4172-89B2-9CFDB5EBF31B/Documents/yourFileName.pdf")
        {
            webVw.load(URLRequest(url: url), mimeType: url, textEncodingName: <#String#>, baseURL: <#URL#>)
        }

Comment: Use loadRequest method only with request parameter

Comment: webVw.loadRequest(pdfPath) getting error Cannot convert value of type 'NSURL' to expected argument type 'URLRequest'

Comment: You have to pass URL instead of NSURL. Check my code in the answer.